# Having Different Users and Metrics For Resolving and Closing Issues in Jira

Tags: testing, jira, project-planning

In Jira, we are currently trying to model the way our company does Software development versus software testing. We generally have QA open tickets, Software Dev picks up the tickets (assigns it to themselves), and then QA verifies the tickets after Dev team has resolved it. What we are concerned about is being able to track both Resolutions as well as Closes.

For example, assume two Jira users person A (Software Dev) and person B (QA)

B: opens ticket
A: Fixes issue and resolves ticket
B: closes ticket.

At the end of the day, we want to be able to see
A: Issues Resolved: 10
B: Issues Closed/Tested: 10

Is there a way to do this in Jira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following JQL:

```
# resolved from the beginning of the day
resolution = Done and resolutiondate > startOfDay()
# closed from the beginning of the day, assuming that closed issues can't be edited (default)
status = Closed and updatedDate > startOfDay()
```

---

Having said that, we ended up doing something quite different. here is the workflow:

1. QA opens tickets (in the QA project) after reviewing support issues.
2. The QA have a special transition in their workflow - `pass to developers`. When doing this, the original issue moves to `waiting for dev` state where it can't be modified manually, and a duplicate issue is created in the DEV project. All issue field are being copied. in case this issue has already been assigned than the original `DEV` issue is re-opened.
3. Developer pick this issue and resolve it. Once the issue is resolved, the original issue from the QA unfreezes - moves to `QA after dev` state where it's editable again.
4. The QA team picks up this issue, check if they where resolved and closed them or moves them back to `waiting for dev` if needed.

This way we could have report of how many issues were closed, opened, resolved, picked up by the dev team, waiting for the dev team and so on.

To achieve this functionality we used custom fields to save the fields that where passed from the two types of issues, link between the two issues, and used [Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss) for the issue and link creation, as well as [Behaviours Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours) for filed verification.

In case you need support for Jira > 5.2 instead of Jira Scripting Suite use [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner)